# Intellisense Errors on .DEF file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, intellisense, function

I'm trying to learn C++, particularly exporting functions from my library. I have set up a module definition (.DEF) file which specifies the exported functions. The syntax is compliant with what I have read on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyx1zcd3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

I am trying to understand why I get intellisense errors on just about every statement of the DEF file.

For example:

```
EXPORTS
    LibDescription @1 PRIVATE
    LibInitialize @2 PRIVATE
    LibVersion @3 PRIVATE
```

Yields intellisense errors along the lines of:

```
unexpected token '@'
unexpected token 'PRIVATE'
```

Despite all of these (these are errors, not warnings), the library builds just fine, and moreover, exports all the required functions, so it's really just a nuisance which makes it harder to see the actual code errors in the list.

Is this expected behavior or is there an obvious setting I am missing somewhere?

edit: as is suggested in the comments, the errors most like come from the linker and not from the compiler, as there is no mention of them in the compiler output pane.

**edit2: what is generating the errors is actually intellisense, edited title and tags.**

Comment: Do you mean linker errors? The `.def` file is read by the linker. If the compiler itself raises these errors, you might have misconfigured the build tool property of your `.def` file.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I am not sure how to discern linker errors from compiler errors. The errors show up in Visual Studios interactive errors/warnings window. I can't find where it says which component is generating the errors. I also can not find a 'build action' parameter for the file. It's 'Item Type' is set to 'does not participate in build'.

Comment: Yup, I misused the term. That setting is indeed called `Item Type` in VS2010, and `Does not participate in build` is the right value for a `.def` file (I just double-checked with a new project). Can you look at your `Output` pane for the error codes? It would tell for sure if they come from the compiler or the linker.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi there is no mention of them in the output pane, which I guess means they come from the linker. I've edited my question. But why is this happening?

Comment: Actually, both the compiler and the linker output their errors to the `Output` pane (the error code prefixes allow to differentiate them). If these errors do not show up in the `Output` pane, another component is responsible for them. I strongly suspect Intellisense, but I still cannot explain this behavior. Do you have add-ons installed on your Visual Studio?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi There are no add-ons installed, but you are right about intellisense. When I disable intellisense entirely the errors go away.

Comment: Maybe I got it: In the VS2010 menu, click `Tools | Options`, navigate to `Text Editor > File Extension` and check if the `def` extension is associated with a language editor. It shouldn't.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Actually there are no extensions defined in that dialog at all. Should there be?

Comment: No, it's fine if there are no extensions defined. I'm afraid I ran out of possible explanations...

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi thank you for taking the time to explore the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had **Python Tools for Visual Studio** installed and I suppose it thought that the `def` file was Python source code.
Uninstalling the Python tools solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple explanation for your problem.  So there's something we don't know.  Maybe you can see it from a screenshot of a sample VS2010 DLL project that doesn't have this problem.  Carefully compare it with yours.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the image, Hans. If I start with an `EXPORTS` as in your example everything is fine. The problem starts when I start with `LIBRARY`. Whatever comes after `LIBRARY` gets an *unexpected token* error. i.e. `LIBRARY MyLibrary.dll`, results in *unexpected token 'MyLibrary'*, and from then on out everything gets an *unexpected token* error.

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment is incorrect, even in your example I get an *unexpected token LibDescription*.

Comment: Problem found! I had Python Tools for Visual Studio installed, and I guess it thought the .def file was a python code file for some reason. Uninstalling it solved the problem.